# Multiple analytic functions consuming all memory in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I thought I was being slick avoiding multiple LEFT JOINs and GROUP BYs in Big query with the following:

```
 WITH added_a_boolean_column AS (
      SELECT
        *,
        NOT (DATE(CodedDate) >= "2018-04-01"
          AND DATE(CodedDate) < "2018-04-14") AS train
      FROM
      `XXXXX` )


SELECT 
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY a) as a_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY b) as b_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY c) as c_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY d) as d_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY e) as e_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY f) as f_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY g) as g_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY h) as h_counts,
   countif(train) OVER (PARTITION BY i) as i_counts
 FROM added_a_boolean_column
```

However... it's resulting in the following error:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 152% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 99% other/unattributed: 1% .
```

What exactly is going on? Is:

```
 WITH added_a_boolean_column AS (
      SELECT
        *,
        NOT (DATE(CodedDate) >= "2018-04-01"
          AND DATE(CodedDate) < "2018-04-14") AS train
      FROM
      `XXXXX` ),

    a_count as (
        SELECT count(*) as a_counts, a FROM added_a_boolean_column WHERE train GROUP BY a),
    b_count as (.....
    ....
    ....

    i_count as (..

    SELECT * FROM added_a_boolean_column LEFT JOIN a_count.....
```

a better alternative?

Comment: what the use-case behind first query? it is not clear as output looks extremely redundant and will have same values in all rows - so what he point?!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant its the beginning of a larger calculation that needs a count of each column. I'm tried to simply it to its base case. I'm confused how will the output be redundant? It would look like [{'a': 'aOne', 'a_count': 5000}, {'a': 'aTwo', 'a_count': 6000}].  So you would have a count for each class of 'a' and that would show up as its own column. Yes there will be a lot of repeated values in the count column.

Comment: each column will have its own value. but each row will have the very same values! based on what you have now as first query in your question. this might be because you are oversimplifying your real query when present it in the question :o) - try to run that query and you will see